# what is <flask_sqlalchemy.Pagination+object+at+0x7f6a87687950> that I get from my URL

Tags: python, flask, flask-migrate

In my flask application which I use flask-migrate and Alembic I got this URL" /user/1?sort=ascmonkey=< flask_sqlalchemy.Pagination+object+at+0x7f6a8077ea10 >",while this part is extra < flask_sqlalchemy.Pagination+object+at+0x7f6a8077ea10 >  where is it come from and how can I get rid of that?Thanx

View.py:

```
@layout.route('/user/<int:page>', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def user(page=1, sort='normal'):
    user = g.user
    #condition to sort base on ascending
    if request.args.get('sort') =='asc':
            sortBy = 'asc'
            monkey = Users.query.order_by(Users.name.asc()).paginate(page, MONKEYS_PAGE)
MONKEYS_PAGE)
 return render_template('Users.html',
            user = user,
            title ='Home',
            monkey = monkey,
            sortBy = sortBy
            )
```

User.html

```
   <div class="text-right sortby">
   <span>Sort by</span>
   <a href="{{ url_for('layout.user', page = '1', sort = 'asc', monkey = monkey) }}" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort-by-alphabet"></span>
     name
   </a>

   <a href="{{ url_for('layout.user', page = '1', sort = 'friendnum', monkey = monkey) }}" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-link"></span>
     number of friends
   </a>
   <a href="{{ url_for('layout.user', page = '1', sort = 'bf', monkey = monkey) }}" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-link"></span>
     name of best friends
   </a>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`monkey` is a paginated list of users, based on the query you've shown.  The actual users are stored in `monkey.items`, a list.  Based on what you've shown, you either want to iterate over those items to generate individual urls, or you meant for `monkey` to be one user rather than a paginated list.   Right now you're doing something along the lines of `url_for('user', monkey=monkey)`, so Flask is placing the string representation of the pagination object into the query params.